# LinkedList data structure explanation in Python

Tags: python, linked-list, comments

I managed to find python code that defines a LinkedList class and all the defacto methods in it but quite can't figure out what each line of code does...Can someone comment on it explaining what each line does so i can grasp a better understanding of LinkedLists in python?

```
class Node:#what is the significance of a node
  def __init__(self, data, next):#why these parameters
    self.data = data
    self.next = next
class LinkedList:
    def __init__(self):#what is a head
        self.head = None
    
    def add_at_front(self, data):
        self.head = Node(data, self.head)      

    def add_at_end(self, data):
        if not self.head:#what is it checking 
            self.head = Node(data, None)
            return#what is it returning
        curr = self.head
        while curr.next:
            curr = curr.next
        curr.next = Node(data, None)

    def get_last_node(self):
        n = self.head
        while(n.next != None):
            n = n.next
        return n.data

    def is_empty(self):#i understand this method
        return self.head == None

    def print_list(self):#i also undertsnad this one
        n = self.head
        while n != None:#what is this loop doing
            print(n.data, end = " => ")
            n = n.next
        print()


s = LinkedList()
s.add_at_front(5)
s.add_at_end(8)
s.add_at_front(9)

s.print_list()
print(s.get_last_node())
```

Comment: https://www.hackerearth.com/practice/data-structures/linked-list/singly-linked-list/tutorial/ . just read the theory and how linked list work. then you will be able to udnerstand the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you read up Linked Lists first, you don't seem to understand how they are structured completely https://www.javatpoint.com/singly-linked-list

```
class Node:#this node class is used to represent a node in the linked list
  def __init__(self, data, next):# data is the data carried by the node, next is a reference to the next node in the list
    self.data = data
    self.next = next
class LinkedList:
    def __init__(self):#the head is the first node of a linkedlist
        self.head = None
    
    def add_at_front(self, data):
        self.head = Node(data, self.head)      

    def add_at_end(self, data):
        if not self.head: #this checks if the list is empty, i.e the head node is None.  
                          #Here the new node is inserted at the head since the rest of the list is empty
            self.head = Node(data, None)
            return# this return is used to exit the function, it returns nothing
        curr = self.head
        while curr.next:
            curr = curr.next
        curr.next = Node(data, None)

    def get_last_node(self):
        n = self.head
        while(n.next != None):
            n = n.next
        return n.data

    def is_empty(self):#i understand this method
        return self.head == None

    def print_list(self):#i also undertsnad this one
        n = self.head
        while n != None: #this checks if we traversed through the whole linked list already
                        # this is what the LL looks like: HEAD->Node->Node->None
                        # if n has reached None, then that means it has successfully visited all the nodes in the list
            print(n.data, end = " => ") 
            n = n.next #this line jumps to the next node of the linked list
        print()


s = LinkedList()
s.add_at_front(5)
s.add_at_end(8)
s.add_at_front(9)

s.print_list()
print(s.get_last_node())
```

Comment: Thanks for your time and effort explaining the code, Some language documentation is like was written by robots..You just can't understand nothing

Answer (score 0):

This is simple class rules. Understand class Node as block of Node visually.

Class Node visual image : https://i.stack.imgur.com/459GJ.jpg

Now the node is contains two parts, **data** and **next**. Data contains data whereas next part contains address of next Node.

Now whenever LinkedList class is initialised, head pointer(variable) will be generated as null as basic concept of Linked list. Think head as your agent who will guide you to node to node.

Head initialisation visual image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/PUar7.jpg

Now while doing any action through linked list, you have to check, if there is your agent or not. If head is there, then you can go node to node and perform your actions accordingly.

Next question, what it is returning

```
    def add_at_end(self, data):
    if not self.head:#what is it checking 
        self.head = Node(data, None)
        return#what is it returning
    curr = self.head
    while curr.next:
        curr = curr.next
    curr.next = Node(data, None)
```

See, it is a type of if-else statement. In above code, if there is no head or head==null, you will create a new node. Node all changes are over class not only to method. So, **return** will stop executing next statement of method.
If the condition will not satisfied, *curr = self.head* will start executing.

About the loop, your agent will guide you up to last node and get you each node data.
And last print changing line, that's it.

Loop visual image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vN2pE.jpg

Thanks